# Fundraising for J.M

Tags: discussion

After talking to J.M. and getting his permission, we now have an official fundraising campaign here

---

### [Help Jan (J.M.) to receive his medical treatment (Click me!!!)](https://www.youcaring.com/jmfromstackexchange-1150122)

---

For those who weren't following the chat, let me give some background information. Our moderator and good friend since many years [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50) suffers from issues with his liver and nervous system. The medical tests to find the cause of the illness and the treatment are too expensive for him because he is living in a region where the economy is not great and things that most of us take for granted are beyond reach.

If you want to help, you can do two things:

1. Donate some money. Please remember, it's not the amount that counts. Every tiny bit helps.
2. Equally important: Share the donation link with your network. Many of us have connections to other Mathematica users and chances are in our favor that a lot of them have visited the site and even know J.M.

## Some information about the campaign

I am the "Organizer" which means that the money is sent to my PayPal account. This happens directly and without delay. I will send the money via direct bank transfer to JM. I have been the donation broker in the past and I hope enough people know me to be absolutely sure that every last cent will be transferred to JM. I have most of my personal data online and it should not be hard for you to find out that I'm a researcher from Germany.

I have set the current goal to 1000 Euro which was suggested by the fundraising page. I am more than confident that we will reach this goal. However, my hope is to get enough attention that we might be able to raise this goal and we can provide JM with a bit more than only the quick fix for the current situation. After all, it is likely that he will need treatment over an extended period.

Comment: Great initiative, kudos to you!

Comment: Thanks! Should we publish this in meta.math.se and community.wolfram.com?

Comment: @Kuba I haven't been contributing much in math.SE lately, and I'm still tentative about Community; maybe not for the time being. In any event, thank you, halirutan.

Comment: @JackLaVigne I have edited the post so that it is obvious now that the large text is actually a link to the donation page. There, you can donate and share the fundraising campaign with your social network.

Answer (score 33):

First off, I am really touched that a lot of people care about my well-being. Thank you, all!

The amounts I have gotten will not only pay for clinical tests, but apparently my entire treatment course of four months (assuming my doctor does not tack in a new prescription based on my test results). I will be getting tested in a few hours, and I hope it goes alright.

I have sent e-mails to everybody who sent money in before halirutan started the campaign. If you did not get an e-mail from me, please e-mail me as a reminder; I got so much e-mail regarding this matter and I may have inadvertently missed yours.

Also, I have asked halirutan for the e-mail addresses of those who contributed to his campaign, so I can write you a thank-you note. I hope this is fine.

---

### Update

I was able to visit my doc today with my test results; I talk more about it on [my blog](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2018/04/12/a-health-status-update/).

Answer (score 32):

As I have already posted in chat, you guys are awesome and I am truly touched. Within the few days over the Easter weekend, you donated over 1000 Euro.

[image: img]

As you might have noticed, there is no donation from me yet. As I have to transfer this from my own bank account anyway, it would have been a loss to first donate it via Paypal and then get the money back. However, I will push another 200 Euro on top of what you all collected.
My original plan was to fill up whatever is missing to the 1000 Euro goal but what can I say. I'm simply out of words.

I am truly proud of the community we have. As I'm seeing the names of the donors, I can say that I recognize most them. I'm also touched to see a contribution from an employee of our German Wolfram distributor [Additive](http://www.additive-net.de/de/).

Note that you can still donate and the money will go to J.M.! I spoke to him to ask if I should raise the goal but we decided against it.

### Update 2018/04/13

People are still contributing:

[image: img]

I have transferred 500 Euro last week to J.M. to ensure the money arrives. J.M. got the money within only 1 or 2 days. Now, I have to verify my identity to make a larger transfer through Western Union which included requesting a real physical letter and providing my identity at a post office. The identity-check is on its way back to Western Union and I'm waiting for approval.