# Where in the world is J.M?

Tags: discussion, moderators, missing-person

He is (was) one of the most active and highly respected users on this site, and a beloved moderator. A while ago, he faced some health issues and there was a [fundraising](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2322/37848) to help him deal with it. Since then, he has changed his username multiple times and some of them (especially the last one) sound worrying.

So I dare to ask: how is he doing? His profile page says he hasn't visited this site for more than a month, which is quite odd for a moderator. Does anyone have any news regarding his health and well-being as well as his plans for future contributions to the site? (and please read the following sentence with a non-jerk tone) Is there any policy regarding inactive moderators?

Comment: As you say, J.M is a highly respected member of the community, who has had, for many different circumstances, an intermittent presence on this site. His [blog](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/) has been inactive for some time and he hasn't answered private messages. Some of the reasons for previous absences included health issues and access to a computer. We can all can invite J.M a [*"ko-fi"*](https://ko-fi.com/pleasureoffiguring) which I hope could at least help with the material aspect of these constraints.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'm actually OK (more or less); I just haven't been able to visit as frequently as I would want to due to other things (some nice, some not so nice) eating up my time the past few months (stuff started becoming hectic for me post-Christmas). Things should calm down a bit on my end by late April or early May, and I should be able to participate more actively again. (After all, I don't have many other places where I have opportunities to use Mathematica on things I ostensibly have very minimal knowledge in!)

I'm touched that people are concerned for my well-being; thank you. I'll poke my head in from time to time, but please stay put for now.

Comment: At least this here is a _new kind of community_ — great to read that you are well!

Comment: So glad to see your answer :)

Comment: Happy to read from you J.M.